# Firebase- Not able to get verification code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Below is the main code where I am trying to get the verification code on clicking "send verification" button. But the verification code is not coming. It is not going to next page too. Error is also not there.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mPhoneNumber,mCode;
    private Button mSend;
    String mVerificationId;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp( this );

        userIsLoggedIn();

        mPhoneNumber = findViewById( R.id.phoneNumber );
        mCode = findViewById( R.id.code );
        mSend = findViewById( R.id.send );

        mSend.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mVerificationId != null) {
                    verifyPhoneNumberWithCode( );
                }
                else
                    startPhoneNumberVerification();

            }
        } );

        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                signInWithOhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) { }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent( verificationId, forceResendingToken );
                    mVerificationId = verificationId;
                    mSend.setText( "verify code" );
            }
        };
    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(){
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId , mCode.getText().toString());
        signInWithOhoneAuthCredential( credential );
    }

    private void signInWithOhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential( phoneAuthCredential ).addOnCompleteListener( this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                    userIsLoggedIn();
            }
        } );
    }

    private void userIsLoggedIn() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null){
            startActivity( new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainPageActivity.class) );
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void startPhoneNumberVerification() {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                mPhoneNumber.getText().toString(),
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                this,
                mCallbacks);
    }
}
```

Below is my MainPageActivity. Onclicking send verification button the code has to get verified and open up this MainPageActivity.

```
public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main_page );

    Button mLogout = findViewById( R.id.logout );
    mLogout.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class );
            intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
            startActivity( intent );
            finish();
            return;
        }
    } );
}
}
```

This is my android manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chatserver">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainPageActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using country phone code while writing phone number in your Edittext. 
For ex: use +911122334455, where +91 is country phone code of India.